# Ambiguous user-defined-conversion in Visual C++ (VS2017)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

VS2017 (15.8.7/15.8.8) fails to compile code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    operator int() const { std::cout << "int() 1" << std::endl; return 0; }
    operator int() { std::cout << "int() 2" << std::endl; return 0; }
};

class B : virtual public A {};
class C : virtual public A {};
class D : public B, public C {};

int main()
{
    // Compiles when const version is defined before non-const.
    // The assignment calls const version of course.
    const D cobj;
    int i = cobj;

    // Compiles when non-const version is defined before const.
    // The assignment calls non-const version.
    D obj;
    int j = obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

1. error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'D' to 'int'
2. note: Ambiguous user-defined-conversion

g++ 7.3 (by default and with std=c++11/14/17) and VS2013 (update 5)
compiles this without any warnings/errors related to conversion functions
(even with -Wall).

Why the code is ambiguous? Is this a VC++ bug?

Comment: You should probably submit a bug report.

Comment: Seems like a bug indeed.

Comment: FWIW, icc 18 and 19 also both fail to compile on godbolt

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a compiler bug. I reported it here: [fails to find user-defined-conversion in virtual inheritance](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/390055/fails-to-find-user-defined-conversion-in-virtual-i.html)

Feel free to up vote it so it gets prioritized for fixing